# AWS RDS Aurora - Cross Region Read Replica has both Write and Reader instance?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-rds

I noticed when a Cross Region Read Replica was created for my AWS Aurora cluster - it has both a Write and Reader instance (Similar to my Primary which naturally has a writer in addition to a reader instance). In the Cluster Configuration for the Cross Region Replica cluster - I can see this "Replica" cluster indeed has the `Replication source` tag and its correctly getting all data flowed asynchronously.

Couple of questions I need help understanding this:

- should a Cross Region Replica have a Writer?
- Should I write to it in case of a disaster in the source region?

[image]

Comment: when you select cross region replica, you will have other writer instance, but it is inactive. So, you will have in your main region an active writer instance and in your secondary region an inactive writer instance

Answer (score 1):

I had to explicitly make the read-replica instance (in replica region) as read_only.  Otherwise read-replica accepts writes to it.

Answer (score 1):

Found relevant answer in AWS re:Post:

> "You're replicating to a new cluster, and each cluster needs a writer
> instance. It is recommended that customers apply the read_only
> parameter to the replica, but by default they are able to write to
> this instance. This allows for architectures where the replica is read
> & writable.

https://repost.aws/questions/QUrCbnj0u4TWaz-A1uR-QDPQ/aurora-create-cross-region-read-replica-vs-add-region

Answer (score 0):

I think the name "writer" is a bit misleading.

In the doc for [Aurora endpoint](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/AuroraUserGuide/Aurora.Overview.Endpoints.html#Aurora.Overview.Endpoints.Types):

> A cluster endpoint (or writer endpoint) for an Aurora DB cluster connects to the current primary DB instance for that DB cluster. This endpoint is the only one that can perform write operations such as DDL statements. Because of this, the cluster endpoint is the one that you connect to when you first set up a cluster or when your cluster only contains a single DB instance. Each Aurora DB cluster has one cluster endpoint and one primary DB instance.

So the writer instance is the same entity as the primary instance of the cluster.

In the doc for [Cross-Region Replication](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/AuroraUserGuide/AuroraMySQL.Replication.CrossRegion.html#AuroraMySQL.Replication.CrossRegion.Creating):

> When you create a cross-Region read replica for Aurora MySQL by using the AWS Management Console, Amazon RDS creates a DB cluster in the target AWS Region, and then automatically creates a DB instance that is the primary instance for that DB cluster.

For cross region replication, the new cluster (writer instance) will be created.

You don't need to take care of the writer instance. For the disaster recovery, [promote read replica](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/AuroraUserGuide/AuroraMySQL.Replication.CrossRegion.html#AuroraMySQL.Replication.CrossRegion.Promote).

Comment: I tried writing to the writer instance of Read Replica and was able to . I then wrote to the primary and THAT wrote as well. But after that - replication broke.

Comment: That sounds how Read Replica should be. If you want to write to read replica instances, you need to promote them as standalone.

Comment: Thats what I dont get - Read Replica should be read only. If I want to promote it in case of DR I can..but why does  it then have a writer instance when one  can  write to it accidently? I did exactly this and was able to write to it. So now I have  an additional primary key in my RR cluster. And replication broke

Comment: @DorianMcAllister I guess "Writer instance" is added to read replica just to have ready-for-use cluster in the event of failover. In this way it is not meant to be used for actual data write by DB client but only by replication process.